# Regular expression to extract numbers after a specific semicolon

Tags: python, regex

Can you help me to write an expression for the following string:

```
Multi 3620 IDS; 17120846;9;12.04.2018 
14:09:02;8,531;;pH;24,1;°C;Temp;AR;60%;;SenTix 940; C171412055;
```

How to get just the number `8,531` using a regular expression?

Is there any rule to extract the numbers after a specific number of semicolons?

Thank you

Comment: Which language? Need to know if capture groups are required or if you can use variable length lookbehinds or `\K`. Also, the number of semicolons: Does this carry over from the first line or is it just from the second line? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am using python

Comment: Then add a Python tag as well.

Comment: Is there a difference between every programming language in the context of the regular expression?

Comment: @mahmood227 yes. PCRE allows `\K` so you could rewrite the regex I posted in my answer as `^(?:[^;]*;){4}\K[^;]+` and the answer is the match rather than the capture group. In .net (i.e. C#) you can write it as `(?<=^(?:[^;]*;){4})[^;]+` and the result again the match instead of a captured value. In programming languages that don't allow these two (`\K` reset token or `(?<=x*)` variable width lookbehind) you'd have to use a capture group as I presented `(?:[^;]*;){4}([^;]+)`. Also, some languages require `^` to ensure it starts at the beginning, but python's `match()` does this by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No regex solution

Personally, I wouldn't even use regex for this:

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##DcxBCoJAFAbgvad4DAQKIW/G0dSfFmGLWrRJd9VSaEDHQSeoW3WGLjb5HeBzH/@cbBaCGd00e5r7KFpoT@LyGryhrFBM52MLkjupuNQFKkiVsk4Vy5LuVuqaq5oVym2eScCdoPRW4vdt0PWjw@GKgjdA29vOvKnSDGrWTa9fnkNEbjbWx0u6uMH4WEAkN/1IQvgD)

```
import re

s = "Multi 3620 IDS; 17120846;9;12.04.2018 \n14:09:02;8,531;;pH;24,1;°C;Temp;AR;60%;;SenTix 940; C171412055;"
print(s.split(";")[4])
```

---

#### Regex solution

But if you **must** use regex (for some unknown reason) you can use the following

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/paIvMu/1)

```
(?:[^;]*;){4}([^;]+)
```

- `(?:[^;]*;){4}` Match the following exactly 4 times

  - `[^;]*` Match any character except `;` any number of times
  - `;` Match this literally
- `([^;]+)` Capture any character except `;` one or more times into capture group 1

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##FY1BS8MwHEfP5lP8KQySOUKSprXtjyEyD3rwsu02FWREF1jakGWgiN/Jz@AXq93tHR7vxa98GPpyHH2IQ8qUHGMnWlLxdD5mT2VtFD3eb0D6RhvV2BottJHKSqN0Q8@9tp1qO2XQLKpSA/EBxi40/n5X2LoQcbdGrWbAxvVb/0mtVaDVVLNTr6pQsDTtkpP7IUR/dLzgt93uFS9ziG/7wy94LQrBwkWT4S3vD/wkmH@n0LGrmHyfeZAfaThHroUYx38)

```
import re

s = "Multi 3620 IDS; 17120846;9;12.04.2018 \n14:09:02;8,531;;pH;24,1;°C;Temp;AR;60%;;SenTix 940; C171412055;"
r = re.compile("(?:[^;]*;){4}([^;]+)")
m = r.match(s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```